# how to solve this problem I am a junior programmer

Tags: sqlite, django-models, django-admin

**WARNINGS**:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\19828037\Desktop\APP DE CONTROL DE REPORTES\BackEnd\GestionReportes\static' ***in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'nivel' to reporte without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.***
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
   Select an option: 2
   PS C:\Users\19828037\Desktop\APP DE CONTROL DE REPORTES\BackEnd\GestionReportes>

I need Help!, the connection with the database I have ***by default SQLite3 ***this is as a test in the functionality **soon migrate to mysql**

Comment: That is *not* an error, it asks you what to do. Did you *read* the message?

Comment: I select the options but I can not edit anything of my models that I update install the SQLite extension to be able to make the modification in the tables but even if it does not let me update

Comment: Migrations are database-unaware, so changing the database should normally not make any difference anyway.

Comment: the problem I have is that I can not use python manage.py makemigrations and the migrate before had no problems when I make updates of my models but now if I see this warning message you have some advice to address this problem?

Comment: again, did you read and understand the message?

Comment: I understand that it allows me to enter a default value to replicate it in the rows that already exist but I do not understand how to do it I am entering the fields in the console when I select the option but I still can not and in option 2 to do it manually in my models I have them defined